# Can I redirect Azure Application Insights to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have more than a hundred different applications reporting to the same Application Insights instance.

The applications are running in many different places (our cloud, customer's cloud, our servers, customer's servers).

All applications use the same instrumentation key.

I now need to move to **another** (or new) Azure subscription. Is it possible to redirect the traffic to a new Application Insights instance without changing the instrumentation key?

Can't move the current instance because the subscriptions are not in the same directory.

Don't need historical data.
Just want to avoid the tedious task of getting access to each application's settings to change the instrumentation key.

Comment: You would also need to change the App Insights injection endpoint. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri, don't know what that is but no. Instrumentation key is the only configuration needed.

Comment: In Azure Portal => Goto `application insights` navigate to **properties** -> you will find an option change subscription  [image1](https://i.imgur.com/naKu1Ts.png)  [image2](https://i.imgur.com/39B53XJ.png)

Comment: @Harshitha, thank you for your reply. Moving requires "The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant.". That is why I asked how to redirect to a new instance. Sorry. I will update the question.

Comment: To change Azure subscription directory,  
Go to azure portal Search for Subscriptions -> change directory
refer the  [image](https://i.imgur.com/6266rRs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Harshitha suggested you can create a new subscription in current directory, then move Application Insights resource to that subscription and finally move the subscription to target directory.

Alternatively you can open a support ticket and see whether something like this can be done internally (though most likely the first approach will be recommended first anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above problem by fallowing below steps

1. Create a New Subscription
2. Goto Azure portal Search for **subscriptions** -> **Add**-> **New Subscription**
3. After Creating the subscription Select the **application insights** Which you want to move to **new Subscription**

[image]

5. To move application insights select  Subscription and Resource Group as shown below

[image]

6. After the above step you will see that selected application insights are moving from  **old Subscription** to   **New subscription** and New Resource Group which you have selected in the above step
7. you can change the directory in azure portal
8. open azure portal and search for Subscriptions click on the subscription which you want to **change the directory**   take below picture as reference

[image]